# What do we call <P = any> on ReactElement

Tags: reactjs

I have a question:

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | 
    JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }
```

What does it mean: " P = any". I know that this is generic of Typescript, but I don't understand why having "=" in here.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<P = any>` means that type *any* is a **default** type for P when P is not provided explicitly.

Short example:

```js
interface R <P = any,T = any> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
    }


const a:R<number, number> = {type:22, props:333} //only numbers for type and props
const b:R = {type:null, props:'any'} //any type for type and props
```

Comment: you are welcome, added a short example as well

Comment: I'm reading the source of ReactJS to learn more. I have searched the answer of my question on Internet, unfortunately, I just find the generic guide on Typescript. But it's not what I expected. Again, thank you so much for your response